# Capturing resource size in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that takes a URL and shows all the resources the browser needs to display the page that URL points to, along with their sizes over the network (compressed) and sizes on the client (decompressed).

I've been able to tap into required resources by adding a listener to [chrome.experimental.webRequest.onCompleted](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html#event-onCompleted). However, this callback doesn't allow me to see the size of headers.

I think that adding a listener to [chrome.experimental.devtools.network.onRequestFinished](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.devtools.network.html#event-onRequestFinished) which calls [chrome.experimental.devtools.network.getHAR](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.devtools.network.html#method-getHAR) would do the trick, but I'm not able to use anything in [chrome.experimental.devtools.network](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.devtools.network.html) as I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'network' of undefined`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the error you're getting, have you read and understood [how to use experimental APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.html#using)? Also, are you aware of [limitations of these APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.html#overview)?

Comment: Yes to both. This is just a tool for internal use only, and I'm packaging the version of Chrome I use with the extension so that we can use it in the future. I solved the problem with something like this:

chrome.experimental.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
  function(details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.responseHeaders[i].name === 'Content-Length') {
        console.log(details.url + ': ' + details.responseHeaders[i].value +
                    'bytes');
      }
    }
  },
  {},
  ["responseHeaders"]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the compressed size is in the header, you can get it like this:

```
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
  function(details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.responseHeaders[i].name === 'Content-Length') {
        console.log(details.url + ': ' + details.responseHeaders[i].value +
                    'bytes');
      }
    }
  },
  {},
  ["responseHeaders"]);
```